# Add JavaScript code to the backend

Tags: javascript

I want to run some JavaScript code during the document ready phase.

Where can I place this code so that it runs each time a page is loaded?
I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add the code in your theme. This is done by adding

```
scripts[] = path/to/file.js
```

in your theme's `.info` file. If for any reason don't want to handle this in your theme, you could instead add the javascript from within a module, using `hook_init`

```
function module_name_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/path/to/file.js');
}
```

For the javascript to execute on document ready, you can either use jQuery's ready event, or use a behavior.

This could look like this:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery's document ready event
  });
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.name = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Drupal's behavior execute on document ready.
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Direct usage of the jQuery's ready shouldn't be encouraged in Drupal. Behaviors have the advantages of being applied to dynamically updated content and have proper access to settings.

Comment: @PierreBuyle There are cases where the behavior functionality isn't what you want. Fx you only make the code run once per page load. That is why I added it as an alternate example.

Comment: Yep, but your answer doesn't provide any hint on which solution to use on which situation, prompting newcomers to stick with the good old $(document).ready they may already know about.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define it inside your theme; for a more in depth explanation see Managing [JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722), and use something like this inside your JavaScript file:

```js
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.example', context).click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle('show');
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

You can also do it from your module.